# Mac Book Pro Partition Query

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation

Right so I have a Mac Book Pro, with a 256 GB drive. I recently partitioned it so I could install Linux on it, and it's been running perfectly but now I plan on installing Ubuntu instead of my current Linux install.

So I've created a Ubuntu live USB, and plugging it in I get it running and I start up GParted. And this is where I am confused.

When adding up the capacity of the partitions, it comes to 233 GB (as also shown in the top right of GParted, yes I know). Which is certainly less than 256..?

Also, it appears that my Linux install is only 10 GB with a 8 GB linux-swap and I can confirm this when running my Linux as it only has 10 GB of space. But when I created my partitions for Linux I created a 30 GB partition for it to use, and I installed it to there...? Is this why I have missing hard drive space? Where is it?

All in all, I would like to wipe my current Linux install and everything to do with it, and install Ubuntu without touching my Mac partitions (although maybe I should increase the size of the Ubuntu partition? Advice please.)

Any help would be appreciated. Step by step would be helpful, as most of my knowledge is with Windows and OS X.

Also if it helps, I'm using rEFInd boot manager.

[image: 1]

Comment: 10 GB is a bit too small for normal usage. Ind I do not think you need that big a swap partition unless you plan to use hibernation.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest to increase the size of the Ubuntu partition.

You need to right-click it and unmount first. Also you will need to turn swap off the same way with the swap partition.

Then you will be able to reduce the size of hfs partition and expand the Ubuntu partition.

Also I do not think you need that big swap partition, if you do not plan to use hibernation.

Regarding the total size, it is OK. HDDs never have the capacity that is written on the label.

Answer (score 1):

Your hard disk size is 233.76 only and not 256 GB. It's a marketing thing or they might not use the proper factor like 1K = 1024 bytes...my SSD which as per the advertisement should be 512 GB is essentially only 485 GB only.

You can install Ubuntu Desktop 14.04 LTS or 15.10 in less than 10 GB and it works perfectly fine. But you need more space for various applications you are going to store. It all depends on your needs.

I will suggest your can free up some space from /dev/sda2 which is around 215 GB using gparted in Linux. But any such operations you are doing - please make a backup of your important data.

Comment: Okay, one puzzle though. When I originally set up to install my initial Linux, I installed it to a 30 GB partition. What happened here then? Any reason why it only shows it as having 10 GB?

Comment: @ShadyActual. As per the images posted by you - your linux partition is only 10.12 GB. As Pilot6 also suggested increase the size for this. You could very well decrease the size of swap partition unless you have some very specific use of it.

Comment: Actually, disk manufacturers who are the ones in the right on the units. Specifically, k, M, G, and so on are SI units, which are in power-of-10 multiples. (Relatively) new power-of-2 units, called IEEE-1541 units, are now used in most disk-related programs that really mean those values, at least in Linux. See [this page](http://stopabusingsiprefixes.org/stopabusing.html) for more on this topic.